# Topic test_1 not present in metadata after 0 ms

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, sasl

I have create 3 topics as test, test_1 and test_2. While uploading data to topic test is working fine, however application fails to upload data on other topics (test_1 and test_2).
Below is the exception :
  `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test_1 not present in metadata after 0 ms.`

The partition and replication factor are same  for all the topics. Replication factor is set to 2 and parition is set to 3.

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=1

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set,
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/var/app/kafka/

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=24

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=<Zookeeper servers>

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
ssl.truststore.location = <TrustStore Location>
ssl.truststore.password = <TrustStore Password>
ssl.keystore.location = <KeyStore Location>
ssl.keystore.password = <KeyStore Password>
security.protocol = SASL_SSL
ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2
sasl.enabled.mechanisms = SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = SCRAM-SHA-256
security.inter.broker.protocol = SASL_SSL
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm =
listeners = PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SASL_SSL://0.0.0.0:9093
advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://<IP in format xx.xxx.xx.xx>:9092,SASL_SSL://<IP in format xx.xxx.xx.xx>:9093
listener.name.sasl_ssl.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config = org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='<UserName>' password='<Password>';
```

I am using regular java client to connect to kafka with property "max.block.ms=0". with dependency as compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.3.0'.

Below is the code snippet :

```
private KafkaProducer createProducer(){
        Properties properties=new Properties();
        properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, <KAFKA HOST>+":9093");
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, config.getInt(ConfigKeys.OPS_KAFKA_METADATA_TIMEOUT));
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG,"");
        properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,<TrustStore location>);
        properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,<TrustStore password>);
        properties.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENABLED_PROTOCOLS_CONFIG, "TLSv1.2");
        properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL"));
        properties.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "SCRAM-SHA-256");
        properties.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='<username>' password='<password>';");
        
        return new KafkaProducer<Long,String>(properties);
    }



public void publish(String jsonMessage){
        logger.info("Kafka queue topic name : {}",topicName);
        final ProducerRecord<Long, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, jsonMessage);

        producer.send(record, (metadata, exception) -> {
            MdcUtil.setLogTraceId(logTraceId);
            long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            if (metadata != null) {
                logger.info("Publishing message to Kafka queue(topic={}) success!" ,topicName);
            } else {
                logger.error("Failed publishing message to Kafka queue(topic={}) with reason {}",topicName ,exception);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: @OneCricketeer : My server.properties is : 
broker.id=1
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
log.retention.hours=24
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

(1/2)

Comment: (2/2) @OneCricketeer
security.protocol = SASL_SSL
ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2
sasl.enabled.mechanisms = SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = SCRAM-SHA-256
security.inter.broker.protocol = SASL_SSL
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm =
org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='xxxx' password='xxxx';

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am using regular java client to connect to kafka with property "max.block.ms=0". with dependency as 
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: '2.3.0'

Comment: Have you been able to use kafka-console-producer with the same SASL + SSL configuration properties? Also, you seem to be missing a keystore location and password

Comment: @OneCricketeer : I am able to upload data on one of the topic "test" however its not working with "test_1" and "test_2", provided that the code is same for all three topics. I will check with "kafka-console-producer"

Comment: As mentioned, you might be running into authorization issues on anything except for test_1 topic... Did you setup any ACLs in the cluster?